# Find first over several streams of different collection Types

Tags: concurrency, java-8, java-stream

```
public class ImmutableCrazySquares { 
   private final List<Square> xraySquare;
   private final Map<String, Set<Square>> yankeSquare
   private final Map<String, Set<Square>> zuloSquare;
    .
    .
    .
   @VisibleForTesting
   private boolean exists(String squareId) {
    boolean matches = yankeSquare.values().stream().anyMatch(squares ->
        squares.stream().anyMatch(square -> square.getId().equals(squareId)));
    if (!matches) {
        matches = xraySquare.stream()
            .anyMatch(square -> square.getId().equals(squareId));
    }
    if (!matches) {
        matches = zuloSquare.values().stream().anyMatch(squares ->
            squares.stream().anyMatch(square -> square.getId().equals(squareId)));
    }
    return matches;
   }
}
```

The above class has a dozen methods but right now I just want to focus on this exists methods.
In essence I want to look at the 3 collections xraySquare, yankeSquare, zuloSquare and if the id I sent is in any of them I want to return true.
Sadly the Key on both the Maps are not the Id and therefore cannot be used for this action. To get the Id I need to drill in the values and call getId(). Since this is a method for tests I do not want to pollute the class with an adicional collection with all ids that exist.
Is there an easy way to concurrently look at all 3 collections and stop as soon as 1 finds the result?

Comment: `return Stream.concat(xraySquare.stream(),  Stream.of(yankeSquare, zuloSquare) .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream()).flatMap(Set::stream)) 
  .anyMatch(square -> square.getId().equals(squareId));`

Comment: @Holger will that actually outperform the original code? Are those flatmaps heavy at all ? or negligible? Does anyMatch run concurrently?

Comment: Streams never run concurrently, unless you request it explicitly (e.g. by inserting `parallel()` into the chain). For sequential execution, the performance will be roughly the same, though, before Java 10, the `flatMap` is not as lazy as it should be. But for testing code, that’s nothing to worry about, especially as this minor problem will disappear when updating to Java 10 or newer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concurrently might turn out to be slower than sequentially, so your code IMO is just fine. It can be slightly improved:

```
return 
   yankeSquare.values()
              .stream()
              .flatMap(Set::stream)
              .map(Square::getId)
              .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(squareId)) ||

   xraySquare.stream()
             .map(Square::getId)
             .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(squareId)) ||

   zuluSquare.values()
              .stream()
              .flatMap(Set::stream)
              .map(Square::getId)
              .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(squareId))
```

Or even simpler, but not as lazy as you have it in your code:

```
  Stream.concat(xraySquare.stream(), 
                Stream.of(yankeSquare, zuloSquare)
                      .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream))
        .map(Square::getId)
        .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(squareId))
  )
```

Basically it flattens all your Collections to `Stream<String>` and check against that with `anyMatch`